# Initializing the class already throws missing arguments

Tags: php

I don't know what I'm doing wrong anymore.
Not even using the function and I already have missing arguments left and right thrown in the error logs, strangely it still does the job and returns the wanted info like my other classes, but I have no clue why these two aren't just shutting up.

```
<?php    
  include_once "classes/getT.php";
  include_once "classes/getC.php";

  $getT = new getT();
  $getC = new getC();
?>
```

The code from both includes are completely similiar just a different URL for CURL and other variables to pass.

```
<?php
   class getT{
    function getT ($tID, $count, $offset) {
      $url = "...?tId=$tID&count=$count&offset=$offset";
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

      $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      return $curl_response;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Required parameters ($tID, $count, $offset) when you make a method name the same as the class name it operates like a __construct() OR

Comment: I already have similar classes, that have no problem beeing instantiated exactly the same, I spend the last 3 hours trying to figure out what makes them different to the point where I copy pasted and changed just the variable, function and class names, and it just happend again. Also I tried to instantiate the working ones, no errors. That's why I'm clueless

Comment: Simple test, change the method name to `getTx` and it the error goes away >>>>>

Comment: If you turn error reporting on, you shoudl see `Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; getT has a deprecated constructor`

Comment: No, just:
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for getT::getT()
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for getT::getT()
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 3 for getT::getT()

And the getTx makes no sense to me unless it's hardcoded and just so I can say it doesnt work, I tried it. And it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the class:

```
<?php
   class getT{
    function getT ($tID, $count, $offset) {
      $url = "...?tId=$tID&count=$count&offset=$offset";
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

      $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      return $curl_response;
    }
  }
?>
```

And you create a new object like this:

```
$getT = new getT();
```

you will get missing arguments because you haven't supplied the arguments that you have in your constructor `($tID, $count, $offset)`

**You have three arguments, therefore you have to add:**

```
$getT = new getT(4, 50, 0); //or whatever values you have
```

---

You should really consider changing the way you name constructors today to (It's easy to do and you might regret if you don't do this later on when PHP is updated)

```
<?php
   class getT{
    public function __construct($tID, $count, $offset) {
      $url = "...?tId=$tID&count=$count&offset=$offset";
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

      $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      return $curl_response;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ok I see why It did work with my other classes. Having more than one function did not trigger the warning.
Other than that, why I didn't give those variables over to the constructor is, they are declared later and also changed during several loops. I thouhgt I could just instantiate the class and give the needed variables over to the function, when they are needed, which works, but this is most likely not a good solution

Comment: I'm not sure I understand to 100% what you mean but I'm glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you try to use old-style php constructor (via method with name same as name of the class). It have three arguments, and you must provide they when you create new object of your class:

```
  $getT = new getT($tID, $count, $offset);
  $getC = new getC($tID, $count, $offset);
```

Comment: This will fix the warnings, but still don't know why out of all of them these two are the ones complaining about it. The others also need arguments passed and they are instantiated the same way, without giving them the respective arguments.

Comment: I forgot to add, that this of course throws "Undefined Variable", since they aren't declared upfront.

Comment: @KimMitteregger - they must be declared before sending them into the constructor!

Comment: @kim-mitteregger To let us better understand your situation, you might show us the code of the other class, `getC`, and we will see the difference between two classes, which cause the error.